# creating a new version in .net 4.5 by updating my current .net 3.5 application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

Is it possible to update the current .net 3.5 application to  .net 4.5 to use in Windows8.
What all things should i do?

Thanks

Comment: Install VS 2012 and follow the steps of the wizard. What went wrong when you tried this?

Comment: Regardless of designing and features if you want to update the framework of the application then simply you can go to properties of the project and change the target framework of the application.

Comment: @CodyGray unless I'm very mistaken that just updates the solution to VS 2012, it doesn't change any of the target frameworks and such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very possible. To change a project to a different version of .NET, assuming you have .NET 4.5 installed and VS 2012:

Open the Properties file, select Application from the left side and then use the Target Framework drop down.

[image: 1]

As for what you will need to change that's a far deeper answer. Most likely you won't even know until you convert the project over and try to build it.

Comment: what can i do if i have no VS2012

Comment: same thing with what @mr.smors instructed, just go over the Application Property then change its Target Framework.